# Uploading compressed TextProperty data to dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to match my local development datastore to the production datastore using the appcfg download_data and upload_data commands, and am hitting a problem with a Kind that has a  TextProperty with compressed=True.  There is a page that displays that TextProperty, and when I accept it a UnicodeDecodeError is raised.  That same page works fine on the production site though.  The same code is producing different outputs on development and production, so the data must be the issue here.  Is there a gotcha I'm hitting when downloading/uploading compressed data?  I've tried doing some unsuccessful unicode-fu to get the data in the right format, and even tried ungzipping it, but neither has worked.  Any help is greatly appreciated!